# Angular 2 Price Filter Pipe - Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms, angular2-pipe, pipes-filters

I would like to create a price filter that filters out the products based on two variables. These two variables are the Minimum Price and The Maximum Price.

Currently I've only implemented the Minimum price to make thing easier to understand. but when adding the  `| priceFilter:priceMinFilter` pipe after the *ngFor directive I get this "`Cannot read property '0' of undefined`" error.

I'm trying to get my head around this issue, can anyone give some advice or tell me what am I doing wrong here? Thanks.

Here is a plunk: https://plnkr.co/tU82lO

app.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'src/app.html',
  styleUrls: ['src/app.css']
})

export class App {

  @Input() priceMinFilter: number;

  filterPrice(filter) {
    this.priceMinFilter = filter.priceMin;
  }

  _productList = [
    {
      "name": "Product One",
      "price": 600,
    },
    {
      "name": "Product Two",
      "price": 1100,
    },
    {
      "name": "Product Three",
      "price": 2150,
    },
    {
      "name": "Product Four",
      "price": 3500,
    },
    {
      "name": "Product Five",
      "price": 4300,
    },
    {
      "name": "Product Six",
      "price": 5400,
    },
    {
      "name": "Product Seven",
      "price": 6900,
    },
    {
      "name": "Product Eighth",
      "price": 14000,
    },
    {
      "name": "Product Nine",
      "price": 26000,
    },
    {
      "name": "Product Ten",
      "price": 30000,
    },
    {
      "name": "Product Eleven",
      "price": 160000,
    },
    {
      "name": "Product Twelve",
      "price": 1000000,
    }
  ]

}
```

app.component.html

```
<!-- Title -->
<h2 class="title">Price Filter Pipe with Data Driven Form Approach</h2>

<!-- Filter -->
<zt-filter (filterPrice)='filterPrice($event)'></zt-filter>

<!-- Notification -->
<div class="note" *ngIf="priceMinFilter">
    <span>Filtering Products from <strong>{{ priceMinFilter }}</strong></span>
</div>

<!--Product List -->
<div class="price-list">
    <div class="product-item" *ngFor="let _product of _productList | priceFilter:priceMinFilter">
        <span class="name">{{ _product.name }}</span><span class="price">{{ _product.price | currency:'USD':true:'1.0-2' }}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

filter.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'zt-filter',
  templateUrl: 'src/filter.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['src/filter.component.css']
})
export class FilterComponent implements OnInit {

 // Initializing Properties
  priceMinFilter: number;

  priceFilterForm: FormGroup;

  // Outputs
  @Output() filterPrice: EventEmitter<{
    priceMin: number,
  }> = new EventEmitter<{
    priceMin: number,
  }>();

  // Constructor
  constructor() {
    this.priceFilterForm = new FormGroup({
      priceMin: new FormControl('any')
    });

    this.priceFilterForm.controls['priceMin'].valueChanges.subscribe(
      (data: any) => console.log(data)
    )
  }

  // From Actions
  onSubmit() {
    this.filterPrice.emit({
      priceMin: this.priceMinFilter
    });
  }

  // Data
  _priceOptions = [
    { "valueP": null },  
    { "valueP": 500 }, 
    { "valueP": 1000 }, 
    { "valueP": 2000 }, 
    { "valueP": 3000 }, 
    { "valueP": 4000 }, 
    { "valueP": 5000 }, 
    { "valueP": 10000 }, 
    { "valueP": 20000 }, 
    { "valueP": 30000 }, 
    { "valueP": 40000 }, 
    { "valueP": 50000 }, 
    { "valueP": 60000 }, 
    { "valueP": 70000 },
    { "valueP": 80000 }, 
    { "valueP": 90000 }, 
    { "valueP": 100000 }, 
    { "valueP": 150000 }, 
    { "valueP": 200000 }
  ]
}
```

filter.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="priceFilterForm" class="price-filter-form" autocomplete="off" novalidate (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="form-group">

        <!-- Min Price Select -->
        <label for="price-min">Min Price</label>
        <select id="price-min" class="form-control" name="pricemin" [(ngModel)]="priceMinFilter" formControlName="priceMin">
      <option *ngFor="let _priceMin of _priceOptions" [value]="_priceMin.valueP">{{ _priceMin.valueP | currency:'USD':true:'1.0-2' }}</option>
    </select>

        <!-- Filter Button -->
        <button type="submit">Filter by Minimum Price!</button>

    </div>
</form>
```

filter.pipe.ts

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'priceFilter'
})
export class PriceFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value, args?) {
    // ES6 array destructuring
    let [minPrice] = args;
    return value.filter(_product => {
        return _product.valueP >= +minPrice;
    });
  }
}
```

Thanks you!

Comment: i have solve your problem please accept my proposal in truelancer.

Comment: see here https://giphy.com/gifs/angular-2-price-filter-l2JhLo3ZhGrJrB2uc

Comment: Thanks @VinayPandya. I've also found a solution for this, I will post it shortly. You can do the same and share your solution with the world. :)

Comment: okay sure @mrTodor

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to solve this issue by creating a custom filter pipe.

You can check out the repository at:
https://github.com/cstodor/Angular2-Price-Filter

filter.pipe.ts

```
transform(list, minPrice: number | undefined, maxPrice:number | undefined) {
  let filter_list = list;
  if (minPrice) {
    filter_list = filter_list.filter(_item => {
      return _item.price >= +minPrice;
    });
  } 

  if (maxPrice) {
    filter_list = filter_list.filter(_item => {
      return _item.price <= +maxPrice;
    });
  }
  return  filter_list;
}
```

app.component.html

```
<!-- Title -->
<h2 class="title">Price Filter Pipe with Data Driven Form Approach</h2>

<!-- Filter -->
<zt-filter (filterPrice)='filterPrice($event)' ></zt-filter>

<!-- Notification -->
<div class="note" *ngIf="priceMinFilter || priceMaxFilter">
    <span *ngIf="priceMinFilter">Filtering Products from <strong>${{ priceMinFilter }}</strong></span>
    <span *ngIf="priceMaxFilter"> to <strong>${{ priceMaxFilter }}</strong>.</span>
</div>

<!--Product List -->
<div class="price-list">
    <div class="product-item" *ngFor="let _product of (_productList | priceFilter:priceMinFilter:priceMaxFilter)">
        <span class="name">{{ _product.name }}</span><span class="price">{{ _product.price | currency:'USD':true:'1.0-2' }}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```